# How to determine violated entity during batch saving in spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have next problem

```
public void batchSave(List<Entity> entities) {
        repositoryJpa.save(entities);
 }
```

If entities list contains already persisted entity i got DataIntegrityViolationException.

Is there way how to know which entity violated persisting?
Researching spring data source code and DataIntegrityViolationException i could find any place where wrong entity can be stored.

**UPD**

```
public class Entity {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "NTRY_TABS_TABH_ID", nullable = false)
public OtherEntity getOtherEntity() {
    return otherEntity;
}

@Column(name = "SORT_KEY", nullable = false)
public String getSortKey() {
    return sortKey;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
public OperationType getOperationType() {
    return operationType;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "activeEntryEntity")
public SortKeyEntity getSortKeyEntity() {
    return sortKeyEntity;
}

@Version
@Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false, insertable = false)
public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}
```

}

Comment: can you show us your Entity please?

Comment: YCF_L, i added entity

Comment: it seems one your Object contain null in one of the attributes annotated `nullable = false`

Comment: No, I persisted entity to DB. And added to List<Entity> entities the same entity. Of course there will be exception. I just want to know how to determine which entity caused exception.

Comment: use a loop instead then, and save one by one, but still not elegante solution

Comment: Yeah. Seems i'll get degradation in performance.

Comment: What do you think `List<Entity> entities` is doing? It loops and inserts them one by one. Turn on SQL logging and you'll see the statement logged before the exception is the problem record.

Answer (score 1):

Use javax validation , and you will be able to do something like this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @AssertTrue
    private boolean working;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 200, message 
      = "About Me must be between 10 and 200 characters")
    private String aboutMe;

    @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "Age should not be greater than 150")
    private int age;

    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    // standard setters and getters 
}
```

And then you can validate this like :

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
```

Take a look at this:
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: And how it can help me solving this particular issue?

Comment: Before persisting you can validate your entities and you will get the entity and the field that is corrupt, in the code inside "violations", and you can get the error, or in your rest-controller using the annotation @valid. Here you will find more info: https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Comment: `DataIntegrityViolationException` is a generic exception, with multiple causes like: `javax.persistence.EntityExistsException`,  `ConstraintViolationException` etc. Do you really think you can overcome these errors through (formal) validation?